# prolog get a term from a compound

Tags: prolog

I get this compound term:

```
e(currentNode,"http://localhost:9000/")
```

How can I get only `http://localhost:9000/` separately from that compound?
Or less, is there a way to transform the compound term to a string or a list?

Comment: It worked, 
I tried with: comp(e(_,X)):- write(X).
Thank you CapelliC :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general you use unification for that:

```
e(currentNode,"http://localhost:9000/") = e(_,X).
```

will bind `"http://localhost:9000/"` to `X`.

You use unification also when you this implicitly by putting variables in place of terms in your query, e.g.:

```
?- comp(e(_,X)).
```

will bind to `X` the second argument of `e` for every matching result.